# How does Jordan think we should imagine 'jaws cracked'?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *The Eye of the World* when the protagonists are in the city of Aridhol, Robert Jordan, the author, writes:

> "You can sleep anytime," Matt said determinedly. "Look where we are. A ruined city. Treasure."

> "Treasure," Perrins jaws cracked. "There isn't any treasure here. There is nothing but dust."

How does Jordan think we ought to imagine 'jaws cracking'?

It reminds of a critique of early science-fiction writing where they took the p*** out of a SF writer who had written 'his eyes rolled across the floor'. Is one to imagine the character plucking out his eyes and 'rolling' them across the floor?

Comment: Your jaws crack if you open them too wide, and the previous line mentions sleep. Put that together and you get a large yawn.

Answer (score 3):

I am inclined to think this simply indicates a large yawn, as indicated in the comments. Note what Jordan writes elsewhere in the book:

> When the door finally closed behind them, Rand dragged the lone chair
> in the room over beside the bed and sat down where he could watch Tam.
> It was all very well for Mistress al’Vere to talk about sleep—**his jaws
> cracked as he stifled a yawn**—but he could not sleep yet. Tam might
> wake at any time, and maybe only stay awake a short while. Rand had to
> be waiting when he did.

So the one you mentioned just seems like an abbreviation of the longer phrase. For some people, when they open their jaws wide enough, some ligaments, bones or  muscles behind the ear make a perceptible sound that is perceived as cracking.

There are [various types](https://healthcare.utah.edu/the-scope/shows.php?shows=0_a1wgqdwy):

> There are actually two kinds of popping that patients report. One is
> when they're almost at their widest opening, like when you when you
> yawn. This type of popping is more of a subluxation where the lower
> jaw bone passes over a ridge in the upper jaw bone, and that's a
> normal occurrence caused by just a hyperextended lower jaw.
>
> The other type of popping is the one that's more concerning, and it
> involves the displacement of the cartilage-like disc which is inside
> the joint. This type of popping occurs usually quietly when you're
> closing. The disc will slip forward of the lower jaw bone. Then when
> you go to open again, there will be a louder pop or crack that happens
> when the disc repositions itself onto the condyle of the lower jaw.

Some people are fortunate, and their jaws do not crack perceptibly when they yawn. Perhaps you fall into that lucky category.